# Hosting a VST/DX instrument in C#/C++?

Tags: c#, c++, vst

I'm trying to get a read on the effort level involved in building a barebones virtual instrument host in C++ or C# but I haven't been able to get any hard information. Does anybody know any good starter apps, tutorials, helper libraries for this sort of thing?

If it matters, the goal would be to a) accept incoming MIDI events and b) dispatch them to the virtual instrument. In C++ or C#, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: My library also, https://www.turboirc.com/vstx might help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To capture incoming Midi events use the C# Midi Toolkit (on codeproject.com) by Leslie Sanford or my [MIDI.NET](http://midinet.codeplex.com/) library.

[VST.NET](http://vstnet.codeplex.com) allows you to load and communicate with managed and unmanaged VST (2.4) plugins. You can also create managed VST plugins with VST.NET that can run in unmanaged Hosts.

There is also a simple C++ open source VST host available at http://www.hermannseib.com/english/vsthost.htm (down at the bottom of the page)

Hope it helps.

Marc Jacobi
(Author of VST.NET)

Answer (score 6):

The [VST.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/vstnet) library appears to be the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

PianoRollComposer.cpp at http://jdmcox.com has a simple routine (VSTthread) that sends MIDI data to a VST plug-in and then sends the received WAVE data to an ASIO driver.